# Retina image blows up 4 times in Xcode

Tags: iphone, image-resizing, masking, retina

At the moment I'm working on a streaming radio app for a friend for iPhone and iPad.

While implementing my designs into code I struck a funny bug(?). I wish to display album art on the background and masking that, using this example [tutorial](http://iosdevelopertips.com/cocoa/how-to-mask-an-image.html).

It works fine on low resolution iPhones, but as soon as I test it on an iPhone 4 & 5 (test devices and emulator) the picture is shown 4x as large as it should be.

[image]

It should display like this: [image]

I've added both normal pictures, as well as @2x's, which come in at 320x320 & 640x640 (@2x)
The last thing I should add, it works fine if I don't mask the images. But I believe the mask works (if it wouldn't be blown up 4x). So probably, the code is magnifying the picture twice, instead of just once.

To add a bit of my code:

```
albumArt = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
[albumArt setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 320)];
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"testPopArt.png"];
UIImage *mask = [UIImage imageNamed:@"popArtMask.png"];
finalAlmbumArt = [self maskImage:image withMask:mask];
[albumArt setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:finalAlmbumArt]];
[appBackground addSubview:albumArt];
```

Comment: Can you post the sizes of the images (normal and retina).

Comment: Added them to the explanation (320x320 & 640x640). The masks are exactly the same size btw! ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You neet to tell the `UIImage` the scale of the :

```
- (UIImage*) maskImage:(UIImage *)image withMask:(UIImage *)maskImage {

    CGImageRef maskRef = maskImage.CGImage;

    CGImageRef mask = CGImageMaskCreate(CGImageGetWidth(maskRef),
                                        CGImageGetHeight(maskRef),
                                        CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(maskRef),
                                        CGImageGetBitsPerPixel(maskRef),
                                        CGImageGetBytesPerRow(maskRef),
                                        CGImageGetDataProvider(maskRef), NULL, false);

    CGImageRef masked = CGImageCreateWithMask([image CGImage], mask);
    CGFloat scale = [UIScreen mainScreen].scale;
    return [UIImage imageWithCGImage:masked scale:scale orientation:UIImageOrientationDown];

}
```

---

You could probably also get the effect with a `CAGradientLayer` so that you do not have to make a new image. It will be a bit less CPU intensive.

Comment: I see, totally looked over that! Thanks, appreciated. Works like a charm